# How to use tkz-graph with syntax and underscore?

Tags: tikz-pgf, underscore

The document below is compiled without error. However, an error (I pasted it at the end) is raised if I uncomment any of the commented lines. Is there a trick to avoid this error?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{syntax}
%\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \SetGraphUnit{1}
  \SetVertexMath
  \Vertex{q_1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The error:

```
ERROR: Use of \tikz@fig@scan@name doesn't match its definition.

--- TeX said ---
\pgfutil@ifnextchar ...1\def \pgfutil@reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \pgfutil@reserved@...
l.48    \Vertex[x=1.5, y=0]{q_2}

--- HELP ---
It's probably one of the picture-drawing commands, and you have used
the wrong syntax for specifying an argument. If it's \@array that
doesn't match its definition, then there is something wrong in an
@-expression in the argument of an array or tabular
environment---perhaps a fragile command that is not \protect'ed.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't need features of `syntax` or `underscore` in a `tikzpicture`, you can restore the category code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{syntax}
\usepackage{underscore}

% directly setting \catcode`\_=8 doesn't work
\newcommand\restoreuscatcode{\catcode`\_=8 }
\tikzset{every picture/.prefix style={execute at begin picture=\restoreuscatcode}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \SetGraphUnit{1}
  \SetVertexMath
  \Vertex{q_1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution is to use the label field for the vertex `q_1` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{syntax}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \SetGraphUnit{1}
  \SetVertexMath
  \Vertex[L=q_1]{q1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```